# How to convert a point to a device point with GPUImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to use the instance method "-captureDevicePointOfInterestForPoint:" of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, but the project uses GPUImageView instead of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.
Is there any way to convert a point to a device point with GPUImageView?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with two steps:

1. Convert coordinates from OpenGL to GPUImageView.
2. Convert coordinates from GPUImageView to other UIView or to a device by using UIView's methods.

OpenGL in GPUImage has next coordinate system: X: [-1.0, 1.0] (from left to right), Y: [-1.0, 1.0] (from bottom, to top).

We can get next affine transform to convert point from OpenGL to GPUImageView:

```
//self is GPUImageView
CGAffineTransform moveToPositive = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(1.0, 1.0);
CGAffineTransform normolizeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0 / 2.0, 1.0 / 2.0);
CGAffineTransform invertion = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, -1.0), CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 1.0));
CGAffineTransform scaleToSelfBounds = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds));

CGAffineTransform resultTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(moveToPositive, normolizeTransform), invertion), scaleToSelfBounds);
```

You can use this transformation to convert points from OpenGL to GPUImageView.